# How to insert a span element into an object (string)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, styled-components

I am working with styled components. I accept an h1 element as a prop from an object which contains a string called *title*. How can I insert a span element into the string of the object so I could style only this part separately as you would normally do if the text was hardcoded?

```
export const heroData = {
  title: `Finance Data`,
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask], and provide a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute for adding raw HTML string to HTML.

```
export const heroData = {
  title: "Finance <span style="color: red;">Data</span>"
... ...

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{_html: heroData.title}} />
```

Comment: @isherwood thanks I a lot for the input. I am just not sure where I should put the last bit?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I edited to remove "hope this helps", which is implied when a person posts an answer, and to move your explanation to the top where it belongs.

Comment: when I add the last line of your comment I get an error: `Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` even though there is only one child.

Comment: okay, i have just fixed it. the problem was that I was accepting an input {title} inside the tags as well. thanks  a lot